# Ubuntu Core 16 on Raspberry Pi 3 cannot connect to Docker daemon

Tags: ubuntu, docker, raspberry-pi3, snapcraft

After setting up fresh Ubuntu Core 16 raspberry Pi machine. 
Using image from Ubuntu Core [web page](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3).

And installing Docker on it with snap:

```
snap install docker
```

I am not able to use docker, as I get an error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Docker service status is inactive(dead):

```
sudo systemctl status snap.docker.dockerd.service

snap.docker.dockerd.service - Service for snap application docker.dockerd
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap.docker.dockerd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-05-03 10:30:55 UTC; 30min ago
Process: 1975 ExecStart=/usr/bin/snap run docker.dockerd (code=exited, status=126)
Main PID: 1975 (code=exited, status=126)

May 03 10:30:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 03 10:30:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 03 10:30:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 03 10:30:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
May 03 10:30:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 03 10:30:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
```

Restarting docker service with:

```
sudo systemctl stop snap.docker.dockerd.service
sudo systemctl start snap.docker.dockerd.service
```

doesn't help.

Docker version output:

```
Client:
Version:      1.13.1
API version:  1.26
Go version:   go1.7.5
Git commit:   -snap-a2d8d8c
Built:        Fri Apr 21 08:56:55 2017
OS/Arch:      linux/arm
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Snap connections for docker:

```
snap interfaces |grep docker

:docker-support           docker:privileged,docker:support
:firewall-control         docker
:network                  docker
:network-bind             docker
docker:docker-daemon      docker:docker-cli
-                         docker:account-control
-                         docker:home
```

Is there any additional steps needed to start docker daemon properly?

UPD: Docker service logs

```
 sudo journalctl -u snap.docker.dockerd.service -f

 -- Logs begin at Wed 2017-05-03 15:56:02 UTC. --
 May 03 16:12:58 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
 May 03 16:12:58 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
 May 03 16:12:59 localhost.localdomain snap[1697]: /snap/docker/91/bin/dockerd-wrapper: 23: /snap/docker/91/bin/dockerd-wrapper: useradd: Permission denied
 May 03 16:12:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=126/n/a
 May 03 16:12:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Unit entered failed state.
 May 03 16:12:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 May 03 16:12:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
 May 03 16:12:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
 May 03 16:12:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
 May 03 16:12:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
```

Comment: There's some useful info in this mailing list post, which might be helpful. Specifically the one about removing debs first. Did you see that? https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/snapcraft/2016-October/001382.html

Comment: The messages indicate that the docker daemon exited prematurely.  Next step would be finding out what its log says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, but got it working again after executing the commands given in [this post](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/docker-snap-fails-to-start/449/2).

These are the commands:

```
$  sudo snap connect docker:account-control :account-control
$  sudo snap connect docker:home :home
$  snap disable docker && snap enable docker
$  newgrp docker-snap
```